# Set image of a button to apps icon

Tags: java, android

I have a button in my app that launches another app (the user can choose which one with a longClick like this)

```
btnNavigation.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
         // Pick an application
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

            Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
            pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, mainIntent);
            startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 1);


            return false;
        }
    });
```

with the onActivityResult i get back an intent

Now i'd like to set the image of btnNavigation to the icon of the app the user has chosen

How can i get the icon from the package the user chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the a drawable of the application icon like this:

```
PackageManager pk = context.getPackageManager();
Drawable d = pk.getApplicationIcon(applicationPackageName);
```